# Can I not show an UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have an objective c application. I show UILocalNotifications in a time interval. But then added this, I want not show determined notifications.

For example, I add a key and value to notifications, and if the notifications received in didReceiveLocalNotification function has the key=2 I want show, but if the notifications has the key=1 I want not show this.

Is this possible?

I'm trying this with this code, but always are showed all notifications:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        //notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:1];
        notification.alertBody = @"Hello!";
        notification.soundName =  @"Alarm-Clock.caf";
        NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"key1", @"1", nil];
        notification.userInfo = infoDict;
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMinute;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
if([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"1"] isEqual:@"key1"]){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the following, but you need to do it before the **UILocationNotification** is fired, not after.

```
for (UILocalNotification *localNotification in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) {

    if ([[localNotification.userInfo valueForKey:@"1"] isEqual:@"key1"]) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification];

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean with before the UILocationNotification is fired? Can I call this into didReceiveLocalNotification? Because I first add the UILocalNotification and then one minute when this is going to show I want not show. Hope be clear and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes you can call in `didReceiveLocalNotification` since the next notification was not fired, it will cancelled.